# Update table in rows which are partial duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql

My dataset consists of daily (actually business days) timeseries for different companies from different industries and I work with PostgreSQL. I have an indicator variable in my dataset taking values 1, -1 and most of the times 0. For better readability of the question I refer to the case where the indicator variable is unequal to zero for a given company as indicator event.

If there is more than one indicator event for a given industry on a given day, the indicator variables of the respecting companies shall be updated to 0.

We can think of the following example dataset:

```
day              company     indicator     industry
2012-01-12       A           1             financial
2012-01-12       B           1             consumer
2012-01-12       C           0             consumer
2012-01-13       A           0             financial
2012-01-13       B           1             consumer
2012-01-13       C           0             consumer
2012-01-16       A           1             financial
2012-01-16       B           -1            consumer
2012-01-16       C           1             consumer
```

So the indicator values that shall be updated to zero are on 2012-01-16 the entries for companies B and C because they both come from the same industry and experienced the indicator event on the same day.

My idea was to work with the exists operator:

```
    update mytable t1 set indicator = 0
    where exists (
              select 1
              from mytable t2
              where t2.day = t1.day
              and t2.industry = t1.industry
              and t2.indicator <> 0
              and t1.indicator <> 0)
```

But somehow that updated all indicator values to 0, and I cannot figure out why.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this, or how to solve my problem with another approach?

Comment: Do you have an extra keyfield (eg "id") to  distinguish the reccords if { day, company, industry } are all the same ?

Comment: @wildplasser No, but I thought about that, too. I could add it with                   CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq;                                                ALTER TABLE mytable ADD id INT UNIQUE;                                ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL ('id_seq');    UPDATE TABLE mytable SET id = NEXTVAL ('id_seq');                    ALTER TABLE mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)

Comment: @wildplasser But what you asked can't happen, because the combination (day, company) is always distinct

Comment: In that case, the solution by @erikxiv is adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add a condition to not join a row to itself (which will always be true), e.g.

```
update mytable t1 set indicator = 0
where exists (
          select 1
          from mytable t2
          where t2.day = t1.day
          and t1.company <> t2.company
          and t2.industry = t1.industry
          and t2.indicator <> 0
          and t1.indicator <> 0)
```

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what was missing. Thank you very much for your answer! @erikxiv